# AspectMock is not mocking a class's constructor

Tags: codeception

AspectMock is working fine, except for mocking of a constructor.

As an example, using a very simple class:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var1;

    public function __construct($var1)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
    }
}
```

With a very simple test:

```
public function testConstructorMock()
    {
        $mockedClass = test::double('SimpleClass')->make();
        $mockedClass->var1 = 2;

        $mocked = test::double('SimpleClass',[
            '__construct' => $mockedClass,
        ]);

        $mySimpleClass = new SimpleClass(0);
        print_r($mySimpleClass);
    }
```

The returned object ($mySimpleClass) has a null value rather than the mocked value.

Everything else works fine, just the mocking of the constructor is problematic. Any ideas how to correct this?